# when using datetime picker format it increases year by 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using datetime picker with following piece of code to format date

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',         
     sideBySide: true
});
```

when I'm using this above format I'm getting year increased by 5 years.

If I'm using

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
        'format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',         
         sideBySide: true
});
```

everything is ok.

Comment: Your second snippet looks like it has an extra apostrophe before `format:`, is that on purpose?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/16t5mLxr/1/ - how to reproduce your issue

Comment: Also which is the datetimepicker plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using format is wrong for the `datetimepicker` plugin.

Use

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
  'format': 'd.M.Y H:m',         
  sideBySide: true
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9h16dLqz/)

```js
$('.date').datetimepicker({
  'format': 'd.M.Y H:m',         
  sideBySide: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.3/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.3/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.date').datetimepicker({
format: "y-M-d H:m", // Change format to this
sideBySide: true
});
});
```

Here is the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16t5mLxr/2/)

Read more about the DateTimePicker [here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).